# Understanding Map and Reduce in Java 8/9 functional programming (lambda expression). How map() and reduce() increases performance?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

This one line of **Functional Programming** code does: 
**2*3 + 4*3 + 6*3 + 8*3 + 10*3** operation.

```
 int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,10) /* closed range */
            .filter(x -> x%2 == 0) /* filter to even numbers in range */
            .map(x -> x*3) /* map */
            .sum(); /* actual sum operation happens */
            System.out.println(sum); /* prints 90 */
```

I understand what it is doing. I would like to know **what is happening under the hood in terms of memory allocation**? We can have the similar old alternatives of above operation as below. This is very easy to understand, but above Lambda based code is more expressive.

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=1; i<=10;i++) {
   if(i%2 == 0) {
      sum=sum+i*3; 
      }
    }
System.out.println(sum); /* prints 90 */
```

Comment: FYI: I removed the `java-9` tag because the stream API you use is not specific to Java 9. I added `java`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First the `lambda expressions` will be de-sugared to static methods inside your class file (use `javap` to see that).

For the `Predicate` there will a `.class` generated (that you can see via `-Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses=/Your/Path` parameter set when you invoke your class.

The same thing goes for the `Function` for the `map` operation.

Since your lambdas are `stateless` there will be a single instance of the `Predicate` and the `Function` created and re-used for each operation. If it would have been a stateful lambda - a new instance would be generated for each element that is processed.

And from your question title `map` and `reduce` do not increase performance (unless there are tons of elements and you can parallelize the process with a benefit). Your simple loop will be faster - but not *that* much faster than streams.  You have also chosen a pretty simple example - suppose you choose an example that does some heavy `grouping` and then a custom `collection`, etc - the verbosity of the simple approach via `stream` would be significant.